# How to debug when my Ionic 4 app stop working?

Tags: ionic4

A bit of context (I have been stuck on this for a few days now):

The first screen on my Ionic 4 app is the login page. Once I logged in successfully, everything works fine. Then, when I log out & log back in, the app just hangs. There is no error showing up on the console. So, my question here is, how can I debug to find out what is causing the app to hang half way using it?

*It hangs in browser mode and when it is running on android.

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug your app step by step I recommend using [chrome developer tools](https://ionicacademy.com/debug-ionic-app/).
First you will have access to your source code, therefore you can put breakpoints at any position you want.
[image]

You can open this window by inspecting your page and selecting the source tap.
To locate the problem you should have an idea about [Ionic Page Life Cycle](https://ionicframework.com/docs/lifecycle/angular)
,
If none of the above works you still have the possibility to console log the code that you want to verify, also the template can cause such an issue if you have for example an infinite `*ngFor` or something that prevent the template from loading.